# Find the largest sum of three sequential values in SQL?

Tags: sql, math, azure-sql-database

Say I have the following table, called `revenues`.

```
id | revenue
------------
1  | 345
2  | 5673
3  | 0
4  | 45
5  | 4134
6  | 35
7  | 533
8  | 856
9  | 636
10 | 35
```

I want to find the largest sum of the grouping of sequential 3 values. Here's what I mean:

```
ids  1 + 2 + 3   =>  345  + 5673 + 0    = 6018
ids  2 + 3 + 4   =>  5673 + 0    + 45   = 5718
ids  3 + 4 + 5   =>  0    + 45   + 4134 = 4179
ids  4 + 5 + 6   =>  45   + 4134 + 35   = 4214
ids  5 + 6 + 7   =>  4134 + 35   + 533  = 4702
ids  6 + 7 + 8   =>  35   + 533  + 856  = 1424
ids  7 + 8 + 9   =>  533  + 856  + 636  = 2025
ids  8 + 9 + 10  =>  856  + 636  + 35   = 1527
```

In this case, I would want the result to be `6018`, since it's the largest sum of 3 sequential values. I'm just starting to learn SQL, with my only other previous language being Java, and all I can think is how easy this would be to do with a for loop. Does anyone have any idea on how I could get started writing a query like this? Does a similar thing exist in SQL?

Edit: Furthermore, is it possible to scale something like this? What if I had a really big table and I wanted to find the largest sum of a hundred sequential values?

Comment: What type of SQL and what version? Do you have access to windowing functions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189461.aspx)?

Comment: I'm running on the Microsoft Azure Cloud. I would be open to using windowing functions if that's the only way to do it, but ideally I'd like to make this query as simple as possible to understand for me since I'm really quite bad at SQL right now, heh.

Comment: Not sure if SQL Server supports this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a213/1

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use two joins to get to `id+1` and `id+2`:

```
SELECT max(t1.revenue+t2.revenue+t3.revenue)
FROM revenues t1
JOIN revenues t2 ON t1.id+1 = t2.id
JOIN revenues t3 ON t1.id+2 = t3.id
```

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c565f/4)

Comment: I really like this one since it seems so simple! Out of curiousity, would there be a way to rework this if we wanted to find a sum of a lot more sequential values? This approach seems like it would become more inefficient the more values you try to add up.

Comment: @Ralph If you have an index on `id`, the number of joins would matter very little, because each one matches exactly one record, which can be located extremely quickly with an index. This approach does not scale when you want the number of consecutive rows to come from some place (say, from a variable) that is not known at the time wen you are writing your query.

Answer (score 3):

If your database supports the `lag()` window function, you can retrieve the result in a single table scan:

```
select  max(rev3)
from    (
        select  revenue + 
                    lag(revenue) over (order by id) + 
                    lag(revenue, 2) over (order by id) as rev3
        from    revenues
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c565f/1/0)

Comment: Good answer, however it does depend if he has SQL Server 2012+ though

Comment: this query will scale well, even when you  have 100+ million rows, because the LAG() Window Function works really well.

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
SELECT 1 as id, 345 as rev
UNION SELECT 2, 5673
UNION SELECT 3, 0
UNION SELECT 4, 45
UNION SELECT 5, 4134
UNION SELECT 6, 35
UNION SELECT 7, 533
UNION SELECT 8, 856
UNION SELECT 9, 636
UNION SELECT 10, 35)
SELECT TOP 1 id, SUM (rev) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS 2 PRECEDING) r
FROM t
ORDER BY r desc;
```

Provides answer `3, 6018`* on SQL Server 2012.

**EDIT**
Query that makes sure that we only get rows that are made up from 3 revenues:

```
with t as (
SELECT 1 as id, 345 as rev
UNION SELECT 2, 5673
UNION SELECT 3, 0
UNION SELECT 4, 45
UNION SELECT 5, 4134
UNION SELECT 6, 35
UNION SELECT 7, 533
UNION SELECT 8, 856
UNION SELECT 9, 636
UNION SELECT 10, 35)
SELECT TOP 1 id, r FROM 
  (SELECT  id
    , SUM (rev) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS 2 PRECEDING) r
    , SUM (1) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS 2 PRECEDING) cnt
  FROM t) as subslt
WHERE cnt = 3
ORDER BY r desc;
```

---

*Actually non-deterministic between `3, 6018` and `2, 6018`. The second/edited query is deterministic.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. But it is possible for this query to return rows that have fewer than 2 predecessors. The question doesn't mention those options, like row 1 + row 2.

Comment: Good point, I've added a second (marginally more complicated) query that will exclude row1+row2 only.

Comment: Perhaps your answer is a bit obscured by the data definition?  Not sure why you're not getting more votes!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    select rev1,rev2,rev3, rev1.revenue+rev2.revenue+rev3.revenue total_rev from 
revenue rev1,
revenue rev2,
revenue rev3
where rev1.id1+1=rev2.id and rev2.id+1=rev3.id  and total_rev=
(select max(rev1.revenue+rev2.revenue+rev3.revenue) from
revenue rev1,
revenue rev2,
revenue rev3
where rev1.id1+1=rev2.id and rev2.id+1=rev3.id)
```

Comment: You are doing (almost) all id combinations here, only consecutive id's are asked for.